# Check whether string a is at the end of string b by defining a new function strend and without it(separately)?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I don't understand what the while loops are doing.Why are they simply incrementing and decrementing the address at the same time.How does this work? 
/*This question is solved.Please answer the second one.*/

```
int strend(char *s,char *t)

{

int len;

len = mystrlen(t);
```

Why are we incrementing and decrementing the address at the same time in both s and t?

/*This question is solved.Please answer the second one.*/

```
while(*s!='\0') 
      ++s;

 --s;

while(*t!='\0')
       ++t;

--t;
while(len > 0)
{
if(*t==*s)
{
--t;
--s;
--len;
}
else
return 0;
}
if(len == 0)
return 1;
}

int mystrlen(char *t)
{
char *p;
p=t;

while(*p!='\0')

++p;

return p-t;
}

int main()
{   
int pp;
char str1[100],str2[100];
scanf("%s",str1);
scanf("%s",str2);
pp = strend(str1,str2);
printf("%d",pp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(*t !+ '\0') ++t; --t;` is very different to `while(*t !+ '\0'){ ++t;  --t;` }

Comment: Do not modify your question to something substantially different, **especially** after having received answers.  If you have a different question, ask it separately.

Comment: This kind of low level string code often turns into what looks like a mess. To help yourself, call the function is_suffix() and don't alter any pointers, use purely array notation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry.New to stackoverflow.Will keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: I suggest you tend to it *now*.  Roll back the offending edit, and if one or more of the answers you have received answers the original question to your satisfaction, then accept one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why are we incrementing and decrementing the address at the same time in both s and t?

Presumably, you're asking about this code:

> ```
> while(*s!='\0') 
>
> ++s;
> --s;
>
> while(*t!='\0')
> ++t;
>
> --t;
> ```

It is deceptive: each iteration of each loop performs only increments on `s` or `t`.  In each case, there is a single decrement after the loop terminates.  This code style would make that clearer (it means exactly the same thing):

```
while(*s!='\0') {
    ++s;
}
--s;

while(*t!='\0') {
    ++t;
}
--t;
```

These loops step `s` and `t`, respectively, forward to the first null character, and then backward one position.  That leaves each pointing to the last character of a string, supposing that neither input string was empty.

The function has undefined behavior is either argument is null, and it may also do if on entry, either argument points to an empty string, or (for related reasons not exhibited by the snippet above) if the length of string `t` is greater than the length of string `s`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(*s!='\0') 

++s;
--s;
```

Since this `while` loop does not have a braced body, only the statement immediately following the `while` is part of the loop. This is equivalent to:

```
while(*s!='\0') { ++s; }
--s;
```

So we are looping through the string until we find a null character, and then we are retreating one character to be at the last actual character of the string.